# How to show data from an Array in a Table inside DataGrid?

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I work with Visual Studio 2019 and WPF, my aim is a GUI where a user can select the machine-variable which the user want to overwatch.
At the moment i have 2 Datagrid's and 3 Buttons on my GUI
I would like to read data from a file and show the data in the left Datagrid[pic].

How can i insert the data into the right Grid and is my beginn the right one?

Data example out of the File:

ablauf          0x200003e4  u32

The first is the varname, second is the adresse and the last is the size of the variable, i only need the parametername and address inside my table.

[image]

I found 100 solutions to connect Datagrid with Table and SQL-Database, but none with an array and a table so when someone know a better approach pls write it to me.

For better understanding my Code sofar XAML:

```
    <Viewbox Margin="0,0,-8,-1">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="400" Height="280">
        <DataGrid Name="tableAllVar" ItemsSource ="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="220" Width="150" Margin="5,30,0,0" FontSize="6" ColumnHeaderHeight="15" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Parameter" Binding="{Binding maschinenParameter}" Width="60" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Adresse" Binding="{Binding valueAdresse}" Width="40"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <DataGrid Name="tableChosenVar" ItemsSource ="{Binding}" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="220" Width="150" Margin="240,30,0,0" FontSize="6" ColumnHeaderHeight="15" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Parameter" Binding="{Binding maschinenParameter}" Width="60" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding maschinenValue}" Width="40"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Name="buttonAddVar"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="178,60,0,0" Width="40" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="C:\Users\mgleich\source\repos\Inspect\Inspect\Resources\Rechter_Pfeil_48.png"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <Button Name="buttonDeleteVar"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="178,110,0,0" Width="40" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="C:\Users\mgleich\source\repos\Inspect\Inspect\Resources\Löschen_48.png"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <Button Name="buttonSaveVarList"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="178,160,0,0" Width="40" Height="40" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <StackPanel>
                <Image Source="C:\Users\mgleich\source\repos\Inspect\Inspect\Resources\schwarz_save_48.png"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Button>
        <Label Content="Alle Programmvariablen:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="8" Height="20" Width="150"/>
        <Label Content="Zu überwachende Variablen:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="240,5,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontSize="8" Height="20" Width="150"/>
    </Grid>
</Viewbox>
```

And my addVar.cs:

```
    public partial class addVar : Window
{
    public addVar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int zahler = 0;

        System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\mgleich\source\repos\Inspect\Variablenliste.txt");   //Erstellung Streamreader
        while (zahler < 2)
        {
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            if (line != "" && line != null)
            {
                //create a new Row
                string[] linearray = line.Split(' ');
                //add the elements from linearray[0-2] into the new Row 



            }
            else {
                zahler++;
            }

        }
    }//End Window_Activated
}
```

Comment: WPF doesn't care where the data comes from - SQL Server, flat file or in-memory array or collection. In all cases, the control binds to a collection of data. In fact, the solutions that load data from SQL Server load the data into arrays, lists or other containers themselves.

Comment: Have you tried using the code in any of the solutions you've already found? Did you encounter a specific problem? It looks like the only question is how to read from a CSV, which isn't really a WPF problem. You could use a library like CsvHelper to load a file into an array or list of objects for example

Comment: I haven't problems to read the file(txt-file), i use the streamreader and that works fine, but i don't know what must i do to show the variables in the grid and is that the right way to use a Datagrid with Datatable or is a data grid alone sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class with two public `string` properties:

```
public class YourType
{
    public string maschinenParameter { get; set; }
    public string valueAdresse { get; set; }
}
```

You could then create an instance of this class for each row in the file, and add them to a `List<string>` that you set or bind the `ItemsSource` of the `DataGrid` to:

```
private void Window_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int zahler = 0;

    System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"C:\Users\mgleich\source\repos\Inspect\Variablenliste.txt");   //Erstellung Streamreader
    List<YourType> sourceCollection = new List<YourType>();
    while (zahler < 2)
    {
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        if (line != "" && line != null)
        {
            //create a new Row
            string[] linearray = line.Split(' ');
            //add the elements from linearray[0-2] into the new Row 
            sourceCollection.Add(new YourType()
            {
                maschinenParameter = linearray[0],
                valueAdresse = linearray[1]
            });
        }
        else
        {
            zahler++;
        }
    }
    tableAllVar.ItemsSource = sourceCollection;
}
```